# Primitive of a differential form

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, differential-forms

How can I find all the primitives of a 1-differential form alpha(x, y) dx + beta(x, y) dy on a simply connected dominion?

Comment: $df=f_xdx+f_ydy=\alpha dx+\beta dy\implies f_x=\alpha, f_y=\beta.$

Comment: BTW, the word you want in English is _domain_, not _dominion_.

Comment: Oh right... Silly me. Thank you both, :)